Compose button failed lock verification and will run slower
When I use Button in compose multiplatform below log printed. Example usage:
            Button(onClick = {

            }) {
                Text("Todo")
            }

Method boolean androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList.conditionalUpdate(boolean, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1) failed lock verification and will run slower.
                                                                        Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
                                                                        and incorrect proguard optimizations.

Method boolean androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList.conditionalUpdate$default(androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList, boolean, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object) failed lock verification and will run slower.

Method java.lang.Object androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList.mutate(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1) failed lock verification and will run slower.

Others buttons like Outlined or TextButton do not cause this log. Is this a bug in CMP?
